# Empty white screen after build with code signing on macOS

Tags: entitlements, code-signing-entitlements, tauri

My Tauri app build works, but when I try to use the code signing feature for macOS build with `entitlements.plist`, it opens and only shows an empty white window.

Here is my `entitlements.plist`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`tauri.conf.json`:

```json
"macOS": {
    "entitlements": "../entitlements.plist",
    "exceptionDomain": "",
    "frameworks": [],
    "providerShortName": null,
    "signingIdentity": "Apple Distribution: ** (**)"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these lines inside my `entitlements.plist` solves the problem:

```xml
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```